# VB macro in excel to save an active doc to PDF with name from a Cell

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, save, doc

I'm new to the forum and I'm happy to be part of it. I've been having this specific problem for about three weeks now.

What I'm trying to do is to create a macro that automates a function for me. I have to deal with tons of contracts all the time and imputing information (like names, adresses and ID numbers) on each .doc than saving that doc as PDF is really time consuming. So I trying creating an excel table where I can imput that information which automaticaly saves to the .doc, this copy + paste is done with the special paste function (if I change something in the excel it changes the .doc so I have the whole contract typed out with some blank spaces that get filled in as I type in excel).

After filling up the cells in excel with the appropriate information I need to "save as" that doc as a PDF with the info from one of the cells (in this case the specific cell is where the company name's typed out), then I need o copy that excel table into a new tab that will have the name of the company (the same cell where the .doc was save as).

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub Autocontratos()

Set appWD = CreateObject("Word.Application")
appWD.Visible = True

appWD.Documents.Open Filename:="C:\Users\lguimaraes\Dropbox\Trabalho em equipe\Laurence\Contracts.docx"

appWD.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:= _
    ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & "Contratos" & Range("C2").pdf, ExportFormat:= _
    wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=True, OptimizeFor:= _
    wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, _
    Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
    CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
    BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\Users\lguimaraes\Dropbox\Trabalho em equipe\Laurence\Contratos"

appWD.ActiveDocument.Close
appWD.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: You've described your idea. Pleas describe your problem with which we could try to help you.

Comment: Hey Kaz, sorry or not placing my poblem. The problem is, whe I run he program  above it shows the Execution time error 438. The object does not accept the property or method. than it lihts up everything in this section after _appWD.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename_

Comment: If I remove the appWD. on the _appWD.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename_ than it says that the error is that _Compilation error, named argument has not been found_

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the beginning of problem line into:

```
appWD.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat Filename:= _
     ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Contratos" & Range("C2") & ".pdf", ExportFormat:= _
```

and keep the other part the same.

**EDIT after comment:**

Than back to 'save as' method and try the followings:

```
appWD.ActiveDocument.SaveAs _
ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Contratos" & Range("C2") & ".pdf", FileFormat:=17
```

This time try to use new instruction instead of your complex '.SaveAs` method.

Comment: Hey KazJaw. I made the changes but the same Runtime error 438 occurred.

Comment: please look into new proposal